# How find this $m$ Value range

Tags: calculus, inequality

let 
$a\ge\dfrac{2^{m-1}-1}{m-1}$and such 
$$\left(\dfrac{\dfrac{3}{4}(\dfrac{3}{4}+a)(\dfrac{3}{4}+2a)\cdots(\dfrac{3}{4}+(m-1)a)}{(1+a)(1+2a)\cdots (1+(m-1)a)}\right)^2+\left(\dfrac{\dfrac{1}{4}(\dfrac{1}{4}+a)(\dfrac{1}{4}+2a)\cdots(\dfrac{1}{4}+(m-1)a)}{(1+a)(1+2a)\cdots(1+(m-1)a)}\right)^2>\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$$
 find the $m\in N$?

This problem is my frend ask me.  Thank you ,

my idea
$$LHS=\dfrac{\left[\dfrac{3}{4}(\dfrac{3}{4}+a)(\dfrac{3}{4}+2a)\cdots(\dfrac{3}{4}+(m-1)a)\right]^2+\left[\dfrac{1}{4}(\dfrac{1}{4}+a)(\dfrac{1}{4}+2a)\cdots(\dfrac{1}{4}+(m-1)a)\right]^2}{[(1+a)(1+2a)\cdots (1+(m-1)a)]^2}>\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$$

Comment: By the way, who is your friend? Most of the problems you post here, are asked by your friend. However, problems are interesting.

Comment: Haha ．　I have lot of some math frend in china Thank you

Comment: $f(x)=(x(x+1)(x+2)...(x+m-1))^2$, you have, $f(x/a)+f((1-x)/a)>2^{-1/2}f(1/a)$. Does this help somehow?